# Unable to Save Picker Result to UserDefaults

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to save the result of a picker to user defaults.  The user default save operation occurs in the class UserData via method saveBase.

I have tried a similar technique successfully with a button but my call after the picker gives the famous error:

> Type '()' cannot conform to view.

```
struct aboutView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

    @State private var baseEntry: Int = 0
    
    let base = ["Level 1", "Level 2","Level 3","Level 4"]
    
    var body: some View {
                
        Text("comment")
        Text("comment")
        Text("comment")

           
        Section {
            Picker(selection: $baseEntry, label: Text("Select Base >")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< self.base.count) {
                    Text(self.base[$0]).tag($0)
                    }
                    self.userData.saveBase(baseEntry: self.baseEntry)
                }
            }
            .padding()
    }
}
```

```
class UserData:  ObservableObject {
    @Published var baseCurr: Int

    func saveBase(baseEntry: Int) -> () {
        
        baseCurr = baseEntry

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(self.baseCurr, forKey: "base")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `body` you can only use Views - you can't perform operations like:

```
self.userData.saveBase(baseEntry: self.baseEntry)
```

You may use `onChange` to save the value:

```
Picker(selection: $baseEntry, label: Text("Select Base >")) {
    ForEach(0 ..< self.base.count) {
        Text(self.base[$0]).tag($0)
    }
    .onChange(of: baseEntry) {
        self.userData.saveBase(baseEntry: $0)
    }
}
```

---

Note that you can also use `@AppStorage` to automate saving/reading from UserDefaults:

```
@AppStorage("base") var baseEntry = 0
```

and use in the Picker in the same way as a `@State` variable:

```
Picker(selection: $baseEntry, label: Text("Select Base >")) {
```

Comment: @AppStorage works great but doesn't update my parameter stored in the class UserData (userData.baseCurr). The .onChange has the most potential but since we are using a local private state parameter (baseEntry) it isn't getting updated by userData.baseCurr

Comment: @GalenSmith You probably don't need a separate `@State` variable in the view. Just do `Picker(selection: $userData.baseCurr` and observe as `.onChange(of: userData.baseCurr) {`

Comment: Picker(selection: $userData.baseCurr, label: Text("Currency >")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< self.baseCurrencies.count) {
                        Text(self.baseCurrencies[$0]).tag($0).  cannot conform to 'Equatable    
                    }                                                                                                             .onChange(of: self.userData.baseCurr: Int) {
                 self.userData.saveBase() --> produces the message: Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type '()'.

Comment: @GalenSmith Use `.onChange(of: userData.baseCurr) { userData.saveBase(baseEntry: $0) }`

Comment: Thanks pawello2222 for the help. I have finally got it working.  I have used userData.baseCurr in both the picker and onChange. If the method user data.saveBase is called without parameters SwiftUI gives the two errors listed above; if I leave the @State private var baseEntry: $0 as a placeholder in the call things work fine.